# Next number in the following sequence

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, sequence

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, and so on. Find the next digit.

Comment: Why so many dislikes

Answer (score 1):

This is the

> Fibonacci sequence from the second term on.

the next term is:

> 34